# Flutter List<List<int>> not adding value after a while with .add() command

Tags: android, list, flutter, dart

I would like to add items to a list of list, but after some iterations the list is not updating anymore.
Here the code:

```dart
    import 'dart:ffi';
    import 'dart:math';

    import 'package:app_co2/visual.dart';
    import 'package:app_co2/exportCSV.dart';
    import 'package:app_co2/dataChart.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';

    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:convert' show utf8;
    import 'package:clock/clock.dart';
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
    import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

    int CO2Data_000 = 0;
    int CO2Data_00 = 0;
    int CO2Data_0 = 0;
    int CO2Data_1 = 0;
    int CO2Data_2 = 0;

    List<List<String>> dataForCSV = [
       ['Time', 'CO2 Value']
    ];

    double screen_width = 1.0;
    double screen_height = 1.0;

    DateTime now = DateTime.now();

    class DataVisualization extends StatelessWidget {
      final BluetoothDevice device;
      final BluetoothService service;
      final BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic;

    const DataVisualization(
      {Key? key,
      required this.device,
      required this.service,
      required this.characteristic})
      : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    screen_width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    screen_height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: buildAppBar(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: [
                  StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                      stream: characteristic.value,
                      initialData: characteristic.lastValue,
                      builder: (c, snapshot) {
                        final value = snapshot.data;

                        //Data collection
                        CO2Data_000 = CO2Data_00;
                        CO2Data_00 = CO2Data_0;
                        CO2Data_0 = CO2Data_1;
                        CO2Data_1 = CO2Data_2;
                        CO2Data_2 = returnInteger(value as List<int>);

                        //Time saving and display
                        now = DateTime.now();
                        String formattedDate =
                            DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm:ss').format(now);

                        //CSV setup
                        dataForCSV.add([formattedDate, CO2Data_2.toString()]);
                        String csv =
                            const ListToCsvConverter().convert(dataForCSV);

                        print(dataForCSV);

                        //Visual return
                        return SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.amber,
                                height: 10,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              ),
                              //Text(' '),

                              Text('Measured CO2 value',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 38, 68)),
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  )),

                              Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(CO2Data_2.toString(),
                                        style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 26, 201, 19)),
                                          fontSize: 70,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        )),
                                    Text(' ppm',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 26, 201, 19)),
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        ))
                                  ]),

                              Text(formattedDate.toString(),
                                  style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 38, 68)),
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  )),

                              Container(
                                color: Colors.amber,
                                height: 10,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              ),

                              Text(''),

                              Text('Previous values',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 38, 68)),
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  )),

                              Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(CO2Data_1.toString(),
                                        style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 1, 38, 68)),
                                          fontSize: 50,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        )),
                                    Text(' ppm',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 1, 38, 68)),
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        ))
                                  ]),

                              Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(CO2Data_0.toString(),
                                        style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color:
                                                  //Color.fromARGB(255, 6, 60, 104)),
                                                  Color.fromARGB(
                                                      255, 14, 78, 131)),
                                          fontSize: 50,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        )),
                                    Text(' ppm',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 14, 78, 131)),
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        ))
                                  ]),

                              Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(CO2Data_00.toString(),
                                        style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color:
                                                  //Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 78, 131)),
                                                  Color.fromARGB(
                                                      255, 28, 105, 168)),
                                          fontSize: 50,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        )),
                                    Text(' ppm',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 28, 105, 168)),
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        ))
                                  ]),

                              Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(CO2Data_000.toString(),
                                        style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: //Color.fromARGB(255, 28, 105, 168)
                                                  Color.fromARGB(
                                                      255, 67, 152, 221)),
                                          fontSize: 50,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        )),
                                    Text(' ppm',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 67, 152, 221)),
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        ))
                                  ]),

                              Text(''),

                              Text(''),

                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  MaterialButton(
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(40))),
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: screen_height / 100,
                                          horizontal: screen_width / 8),
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 9, 56, 211),
                                      minWidth:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                                      disabledColor:
                                          Color.fromARGB(255, 194, 167, 101),
                                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                                          .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) => ExportCSV(
                                                  dataForCSV: dataForCSV))),
                                      child: Text(
                                        '  EXPORT CSV  ',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 12,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                  Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                          15),
                                  MaterialButton(
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(40))),
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: screen_height / 100,
                                          horizontal: screen_width / 40),
                                      color: Color(0xFFFBC02D),
                                      minWidth:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                                      disabledColor:
                                          Color.fromARGB(255, 194, 167, 101),
                                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                                          .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                  DataChart())),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'DATA CHART VISUALIZATION',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 12,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                ],
                              )

                              //Text(''),
                            ]));
                      })
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
     }

    AppBar buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 38, 68),
      title: Text("Data visualization",
          style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
            textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            fontSize: 23,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          )),
     );
     }
    }

    int returnInteger(List<int> data) {
      int converted = 0;
      for (var i = 0, length = 4; i < length; i++) {
      converted += data[i] * (pow(256, i) as int);
    }
    return converted;
    }
```

Here the output:

```
I/flutter (25305): [[Time, CO2 Value], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:19, 364], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:20, 366], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:21, 367], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:22, 368], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:23, 369], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:24, 370], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:25, 371], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:26, 372], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:27, 373], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:28, 374], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:29, 375], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:30, 376], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:31, 377], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:32, 378], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:33, 379], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:34, 380], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:35, 381], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:36, 382], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:37, 383], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:38, 384], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:39, 385], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:40, 386], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:41, 387], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:42, 388], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:43, 389], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:44, 390], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:45, 391], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:46, 392], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:47, 393], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:48, 394], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:49, 395], [2022-03-18
D/FlutterBluePlugin(25305): mDevices size: 1
D/FlutterBluePlugin(25305): [onCharacteristicChanged] uuid: ff469246-6e68-468b-935b-f7e4c6604897
I/flutter (25305): [[Time, CO2 Value], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:19, 364], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:20, 366], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:21, 367], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:22, 368], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:23, 369], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:24, 370], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:25, 371], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:26, 372], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:27, 373], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:28, 374], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:29, 375], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:30, 376], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:31, 377], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:32, 378], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:33, 379], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:34, 380], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:35, 381], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:36, 382], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:37, 383], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:38, 384], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:39, 385], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:40, 386], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:41, 387], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:42, 388], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:43, 389], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:44, 390], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:45, 391], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:46, 392], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:47, 393], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:48, 394], [2022-03-18 – 11:21:49, 395], [2022-03-18
D/FlutterBluePlugin(25305): [onCharacteristicChanged] uuid: ff469246-6e68-468b-935b-f7e4c6604897
```

Any suggestion?

Best regards

Comment: Try adding a `List` in a `List` with the `addAll` method instead of `add`.

Comment: are you sure it's not added? I feel like this is just an output issue. The string is just cut off at some point. You can see it doesn't even show the last item completely

Comment: Mobile platforms truncate excessively long log messages and throttle output.  Try `debugPrint(..., wrapWidth: 1024)` instead.

Comment: @IvoBeckers thanks for the hint. It was indeed a trivial problem with the output console.